# How to specify return value of mocked function with pytest-mock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

The below prints `False`. Is this not how mocking works?

I tried changing the path to the function, but it errors out, so the path seems correct. What am I missing?

```
import pytest

from deals.services.services import is_user_valid


class TestApi:
    def test_api(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch('deals.services.services.is_user_valid', return_value=True)
        print(is_user_valid("sdfds", "sdfsdf"))
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue here is that you're essentially doing the following:

```py
from deals.services.services import is_user_valid
import deals.services.services
deals.services.services.is_user_valid = Mock(return_value=True)
# call local is_user_valid
```

By importing the "terminal" symbol itself you've shorted any possibility of mocking, it's now a local reference, and so updating the "remote" reference will have no effect on the local version. Meaning you should keep a handle on the *module* itself, such that the relevant symbol gets resolved on each access:

```py
from deals.services import services

def test_api(mocker):
    mocker.patch('deals.services.services.is_user_valid', return_value=True)
    print(services.is_user_valid("sdfds", "sdfsdf"))
```

*should* work better.

**This is also an issue with any module using such imports, they requiring patching the point of use rather than the point of definition** because by the time the mock runs chances are the user module already has their copy.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for some more details.

Answer (score 3):

My actual problem was more complicated than the minimal version above. The mocked function was used in a different file.

What helped was to patch the function where it's imported/used, NOT where it's defined. **So provide `mocker.patch` the path to the file where the function is imported.**